# Plot two functions on the same graph in MATLAB using ezplot

Tags: matlab, plot, higher-order-functions

i would like to plot the following three functions in MATLAB using ezplot() but i want the functions to be on the same graph to easily interpret the differences. is this possible? if so how? the three function are:

```
x^3
x^5
x^7
```

thanks,
mysticxhobo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `hold on` to plot them in succession on the same axes:

```
figure;
hold on;
ezplot('x^3');
ezplot('x^5');
ezplot('x^7');
```

Comment: is there is a way to give a label to each graph, or different color to be able to identify them ?