# Area of solid of revolution

Tags: matlab, integral

I'm having trouble doing calculations of volume and center of gravity, of a solid of revolution in Matlab, since I'm new to Matlab. The CAS I used to use, can't do these acions.

I have 2 functions:

*f*(*x*)=-1/2**x*<sup>3</sup>+3/2**x*<sup>2</sup>-x+2

*g*(*x*)=1/2**x*-8

First I have to sketch the graphs of f(x), g(x), -f(x) and -g(x) in the interval x=1 and x=2.5. In the SAME coordinate system. How is that done? I use the ezplot-command, but I always get 1 graph.

F(x), g(x), -f(x) and -g(x), with the intervals x=1 and x=2.5, creates the areas, which have to be turned 360 degrees around the x-axis.

So I have to calculate the volume and center-of-gravity inside x=1 and x=2.5. But which commands do I have to use? How should it be done?

Comment: `hold on` is your friend for getting multiple curves on the same axes.

Comment: >> hold on
>> ezplot(-1/2*(x^3)+(3/2)*x^2-x+2)
>> ezplot(-((-1/2*(x^3)+(3/2)*x^2-x+2)))

Comment: That isn't correct, is it? Because it still gives me only 1 graph. Have i placed the hold on command correctly?

Comment: I don't use `ezplot`.  I know it works with the normal plotting commands such as `plot`, `stem`, `area`, `surf`, etc

Comment: And according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/6603023/103167 it should work with ezplot also

Comment: It worked now! When you enter the 'hold on' command, there comes an empty window up. I kept closing that window, before plotting my graphs in ;-) Now, how do i calculate the volume and center-of-gravity?

Comment: You can use `int` to integrate symbolic functions, or `quadgk` to integrate numeric functions. Read the documentation for them, work out what function have to integrate, and see how it goes.